# Weird double image in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I've been using a Death Star model from Battlefront II in a short clip i've been working on and today I noticed that in renders there's a double image of the Death Star, as if there's a translucent copy of it overlayed slightly offset from it. However in LookDev/Eevee its perfectly fine.

I've tried turning motion blur off, but it still occurs. I've searched for other threads but the only similar thread I could find fixed the problem by turning off fluid sim and I definitely don't have a fluid sim running in this scene. Any other ideas?

Can't upload the file as i'm still having problems with giantcow after 3 months, guess my isp is blocking them or something.

How it looks in LookDev/Eevee:
[image]

How it looks in Cycles:
[image]

Comment: If you hide the death star (with H), is there another one below it ?

Comment: The death star is made up of multiple objects, but they aren't overlapping and if I hide them there's nothing underneath